# Logger in Spring service

Tags: java, spring, logging

It seems that an apache log4j does not work from spring service.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
@Service("updateService")
public class UpdateUserResult {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("updater");

    public void update() {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); //this works
        logger.debug("updating result"); //this does't work
    } ...
```

this is the logger config

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,console 
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n
log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.service=DEBUG,console
log4j.logger.dao=DEBUG,console
log4j.additivity.controller=false
log4j.additivity.service=false
log4j.additivity.dao=false
```

Why is that?

Comment: `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console ` ?

Comment: your configuration is not correct.  You specify logger as `updater`, but you don't define level for it and default is ERROR (this could be not the only issue).

Answer (score 0):

Which package is `UpdateUserResult` a part of?

If the class is not part of package for which DEBUG level is already mentioned in your `log4j.properties` file, then `log4j` will default the logging level in `rootLogger` because log4j follows Level Inheritance which is `ERROR` in this case.